# python related (numpy and scipy)

Tags: python-2.7

when i run command `import numpy as np` or `import scipy as sp`, it gives me error like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named numpy


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    import scipy as sp
ImportError: No module named scipy
```

Comment: You have to install the packages. They don't come with the default python installation. Search `pip install` for more info

Comment: you need to install numpy 

pip install numpy

Comment: If you want to install on ubuntu: 

sudo apt-get install python-numpy

Answer (score 1):

(Disclaimer: there are already tons of well established way / tutorials on the internet. I'm merely posting this to hopefully help out quickly)

## What you want to achieve

To install a library (e.g. numpy, scipy) locally on a machine (e.g. laptop, server, etc.) and import that library from a Python code.

## One of the solutions: Anaconda

One of the popular / quick ways in the Python scientific community is to do this via Anaconda (disclaimer 2: I personally prefer Anaconda due to its ease of enabling me to switch / play with different Python environments). Here is the step by step instructions:

1. Download and install the [Anaconda distribution](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) onto the machine locally.
2. Create a file `environment.yml` and store it anywhere you like (e.g. a subdirectory within your home directory). The file looks like [this gist file](https://gist.github.com/Atlas7/d73cf6b09c7d8cd0bccd950787b52c34) - tweak it to your taste (e.g. choose Python version 2.x vs 3.x, add/remove/edit dependencies, etc.)
3. Within the same directory where you've created the `environment.yml`, create a conda environment by: `conda env create -f environment.yml`. For this particular gist file, it will create a conda environment (called "helloworld") with the specific Python version (2.7) and the anaconda package (which includes the popular numpy and scipy libraries).
4. Activate the environment (i.e. "go inside that environment") by: `source activate helloworld` (replace "helloworld" with whatever name you specified in `environment.yml`).
5. Now you are in the "helloworld" conda environment, start up a python console: `jupyter console`.

Now try importing stuff within this console:

```
Python 2.7.13 |Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec 20 2016, 23:05:08)
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 5.3.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.



In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: import scipy as sp

In [3]: np.version.version
Out[3]: '1.12.1'

In [4]: sp.version.version
Out[4]: '0.19.0'
```

(to quit console just do a `Ctrl + D` to go back to command line)

For step 5 above, also try out:

- `jupyter notebook`
- `jupyter qtconsole`

And play with the python commands.

When you are done with the conda environment, just "deactivate" (i.e. get out of) it by doing this in the command line: `source deactivate`.

Top tip: don't forget step 4 - this defines which conda environment you are in (i.e. which python version and libraries available etc.). I occasionally ommited step 4 by accident and get that error "no module named numpy", etc.)

See [this Anaconda get started guide](https://conda.io/docs/get-started.html) for more info.

## The non Anaconda way

If you would like to avoid Anaconda all together, just simply do this in the command line:

Install the numpy and scipy libraries:

1. `pip install numpy`
2. `pip install scipy`

Start a Python interpreter:

```
python
```

Do the library import stuff within the Python interpreter:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import scipy as sp
>>> np.version.version
'1.11.3'
>>> sp.version.version
'1.11.3'
```

## Additional alternatives

You could try out the Python [VirtualEnv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) - though I've never really used it since I've started using Anaconda.